# MAC OS 10.6.8. version 2.14?

Tags: qgis

I need a version of QGIS that will run on my MAC OS 10.6.8. Can someone direct me to the area that I can download version 2.14?

Answer (score 3):

Kyngchaos offers all previous versions:

http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/archive